# capture value to the left of querystring using regsub

Tags: regex, varnish, regsub

Here is a sample URL:

```
https://mydomainname.net/productimages/1679/T716AP1_lg.jpg?w=125&h=125&tstamp=05/19/2016%2015:08:30
```

What I want from this is just:

```
/productimages/1679/T716AP1_lg
```

My current code is:

```
regsub(req.url, "^/(.*)\.(.*)$", "\1")
```

Which works great until there are multiple query string parameters link in my example above, seems the & is causing me problems.

Comment: is there always at least one query parameter?

Comment: yes there is, any reason for the down vote?

Comment: I didn't down vote. The question looks OK to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capturing non-dots/questions instead:

```
regsub(req.url, "^http://.*?/([^?.]+).*$", "\1")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^https:\/\/[^\/]+\/([^.]*)\.jpg
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This expression will do the following:

- find the subpage and filename from the given link, assuming the filename is a jpg

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/nZ7eX7/1

**Sample text**

```
https://mydomainname.net/productimages/1679/T716AP1_lg.jpg?w=125&h=125&tstamp=05/19/2016%2015:08:30
```

**Sample Matches**

```
productimages/1679/T716AP1_lg
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  https:                   'https:'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]*                    any character except: '.' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.jpg                      '.jpg'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```